# How to get all attributes of a view in crm?

Tags: abap, sap-crm

In Transaction BSP_WD_CMPWB I found a view from the WebUI Client.
[image]
I want to write a method that gets all the values of the attributes of the view structure.
How do I do this?
I think I need to find out somehow which BOL-Object this view structure belongs to...but I don't really know.

I started out like this...but no idea if I'm on the right track there :D

```
DATA:
ls_view TYPE "How do I find out the structure type name of my view, does it even exist? 
lv_query_name TYPE CRM_OBJEXT_NAME VALUE. "How do I find out the query name I need to pass to get my view structure?

lr_query = cl_crm_iu_order_agent=>create_order_item_query_int( lv_query_name ).
ls_parameter-name = 'BUPA_NUMBER'. "This is an example filter for my specific case
ls_parameter-value = iv_partner.
APPEND ls_parameter TO lt_paramater.

lr_query->set_query_parameters( it_parameters = lt_paramater ).
lr_result = lr_query->get_query_result( ).

CHECK lr_result IS BOUND.

lr_bol = lr_result->get_first( ).
lr_bol->get_properties( IMPORTING es_attributes = ls_view ).
```

Comment: You may get interesting information by searching GENIL in the SCN blogs; you may also use the "BOL model browser" in BSP_WD_CMPWB (https://blogs.sap.com/2012/07/17/how-to-find-webui-fields-database-table/); 
for a quick look at GENIL, there are https://blogs.sap.com/2012/05/28/custom-genil-object-model-an-overview/ and https://blogs.sap.com/2012/05/28/custom-genil-object-model-an-overview/; a dynamic approach to get the structure name (I don't recommend it for productive code), there is https://blogs.sap.com/2011/09/12/generic-fm-to-call-the-bolgenil-search-object/

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links, I'll read through them today and try to solve my task